# Connect to QML Chart from c++

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have a c++ class which collects data (currently just random numbers generated between upper and lower thresholds) and packages it into a QVector (QPointF). I have a QML file which includes a ChartView. I'd like to plot the collected c++ data in my QML ChartView (LineSeries), and update the plot each time the data collection function in c++ finishes. I'd like to send the collected QVector to a secondary c++ class to perform the QML ChartView update.

Below are excerpts of the various pertinent files.

data.h:

```
#ifndef DATA_H
#define DATA_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QtCore/QObject>

#include <QAbstractSeries>
#include <QXYSeries>

class Data : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QVector<int> wVector READ wVector NOTIFY wVectorChanged)

public:
    Data();

    Q_PROPERTY(float wValue READ wValue NOTIFY wValueChanged)
    float wValue(){return this->m_wValue;}

    QVector<int> wVector(){return m_wVector;}

signals:
    void wValueChanged();
    void wVectorChanged();

private slots:
    void wTimeout();

public slots:

private:
    float    m_wValue;
    QTimer * m_wTimer;

    QVector<int> m_wVector;
    QList<QVector<QPointF> > m_data;

};

#endif // DATAD_H
```

data.cpp:

```
#include "data.h"
#include "chart.h"
#include <QDebug>
#include <iostream>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QtCharts/QXYSeries>
#include <QtCharts/QAreaSeries>
#include <QtQuick/QQuickView>
#include <QtQuick/QQuickItem>
#include <QtMath>

Data::Data()

{
    this->m_wTimer = new QTimer(this);
    this->m_wTimer->setInterval((1000 / 5));
    connect(this->m_wTimer, &QTimer::timeout, this, &Data::wTimeout);
    this->m_wTimer->start();
}

void Data::wTimeout()
{
    int HIGH = 100;
    int LOW = 0;
    this->m_wValue = rand() % (HIGH - LOW + 1) + LOW;

    if (m_wVector.size() >= 5 && !m_wVector.isEmpty())
        m_wVector.removeFirst();

    this->m_wVector.append(m_wValue);
    m_data.clear();

    QVector<QPointF> dataStore;

    for (int i(0); i < m_wVector.size(); i++) {
        dataStore.append(QPointF(i+1, m_wVector[i]));
    }

    m_data.append(dataStore);

    emit wValueChanged();
    //SEND m_data to Chart.update() here??
}
```

chart.h:

```
#ifndef CHART_H
#define CHART_H

#include <QtCore/QObject>
#include <QtCharts/QAbstractSeries>
#include <QXYSeries>
class QTimer;

QT_CHARTS_USE_NAMESPACE

class Chart : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    ConfigurationChart();

    Q_INVOKABLE void setSeries(QAbstractSeries *series);

public slots:
    void update();

private:
    QList<QVector<QPointF> > m_data;
    int m_index;
    QXYSeries *mSeries;
    QTimer *timer;
};

#endif // CHART_H
```

chart.cpp:

```
#include "chart.h"
#include <QtCharts/QXYSeries>
#include <QtCharts/QAreaSeries>
#include <QtQuick/QQuickView>
#include <QtQuick/QQuickItem>
#include <QtCore/QDebug>
#include <QtCore/QtMath>
#include <QTimer>

QT_CHARTS_USE_NAMESPACE

Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(QAbstractSeries *)
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(QAbstractAxis *)

Chart::Chart()
{
    qRegisterMetaType<QAbstractSeries*>();
    qRegisterMetaType<QAbstractAxis*>();

}

void Chart::update()//Need to pass the m_data QList<QVector<QPointF>> parameter here??
{
    if (mSeries) {
        m_index++;
        if (m_index > m_data.count() - 1)
            m_index = 0;

        QVector<QPointF> points = m_data.at(m_index);
        mSeries->replace(points);
    }
}

void Chart::setSeries(QAbstractSeries *series)
{
    //I don't know how this is called, nor how this actually establishes a link to the QML chart??
    if (series) {
        mSeries = static_cast<QXYSeries *>(series);
    }
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>
#include <QQuickItem>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <QDebug>
#include <time.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <QtCharts>
#include <QtQuick/QQuickView>

#include "data.h"
#include "hart.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace QtCharts;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty(QStringLiteral("Data"), new Data());
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty(QStringLiteral("Chart"), new Chart());

    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
        return -1;

    return app.exec();
}
```

main.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.8
...
import QtCharts 2.2

//I've removed unnecessary QML elements for simplicity

ChartView {
    id: chartView
    width: parent.width
    height: parent.height
    anchors.fill: parent
    margins.bottom: 0
    margins.top: 0
    margins.left: 0
    margins.right: 0
    animationOptions: ChartView.NoAnimation
    antialiasing: true
    legend.visible: false
    backgroundColor: "#1f1f1f"

    ValueAxis {
        id: axisY1
        min: 0
        max: 100
        gridVisible: false
        color: "#ffffff"
        labelsColor: "#ffffff"
        labelFormat: "%.0f"
    }

    ValueAxis {
        id: axisX
        min: 0
        max: 50
        gridVisible: false
        color: "#ffffff"
        labelsColor: "#ffffff"
        labelFormat: "%.0f"
        tickCount: 5
    }

    LineSeries {
        id: lineSeries1
        name: "signal 1"
        color: "white"
        axisX: axisX
        axisY: axisY1
    }
}
```

My question: how do I connect chart.cpp to QML LineSeries to plot the chart.cpp data (received from data.cpp) in the QML ChartView?

I'm using Qt5.9.2.

Comment: What is the difference with your previous question?

Comment: Hi @eyllanesc! Your previous post has helped tremendously, but it used a QQuickView in the main.cpp file which doesn't align with my existing application layout. As you can see, I've built a QPointF QVector as you recommended/confirmed yesterday, and would like to send it to an external .cpp (chart.cpp), and have that file connect to QML, which is considerably different to the QQuickView method in the oscilloscope example.

Comment: I think the Chart class is unnecessary, you could send and update the data directly. The QQuickView is irrelevant to the problem.

Comment: If I can have a function within the data.cpp class to update the chart directly I'd happily do so. I just don't understand the mSeries QXYSeries component of your oscilloscope files; I can't see where the connection to the QML LineSeries is established.

Comment: When you use setSeries you are passing the pointer of the first series from QML:`dataSource.setSeries(chartView.series(0));`

Comment: Ohhh I see! I had trimmed away a lot of the QML ScopeView file to try and simplify it, and have accidentally removed that pointer. I think I understand now how to make it work.

Comment: What do you use wValue for?

Comment: I update some GUI elements in QML with wValue.

Comment: And then why do you use m_wVector? Do not you think you're redundant?

Comment: That may very well be the case. mValue holds the single float output, whereas m_wVector is the collector of the 5 latest values to then append to m_data for updating the chart. I could definitely use m_wVector for both, and update the QML GUI elements with m_wVector[0] for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not necessary to use the series from C ++ (I think the chart class is unnecessary), the data can be updated directly as I show below:

**data.h**

```
#ifndef DATA_H
#define DATA_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QPointF>
#include <QTimer>

class Data : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QPointF wValue READ wValue NOTIFY wValueChanged)

public:
    Data(QObject *parent=Q_NULLPTR);
    QPointF wValue() const{
        return m_wValue;
    }
signals:
    void wValueChanged();
private slots:
    void wTimeout();
private:
    QTimer * m_wTimer;
    QPointF m_wValue;
};

#endif // DATA_H
```

**data.cpp**

```
#include "data.h"

void Data::wTimeout(){
    int HIGH = 100;
    int LOW = 0;
    int val = rand() % (HIGH - LOW + 1) + LOW;
    m_wValue.setX(m_wValue.x()+1);
    m_wValue.setY(val);
    emit wValueChanged();
}

Data::Data(QObject *parent):QObject(parent){
    m_wTimer = new QTimer(this);
    m_wTimer->setInterval((1000 / 5));
    connect(m_wTimer, &QTimer::timeout, this, &Data::wTimeout);
    m_wTimer->start();
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "data.h"

#include <QApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("dataFromCpp", new Data());
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
        return -1;

    return app.exec();
}
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.8
import QtCharts 2.2
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window{
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    Connections {
        target: dataFromCpp
        onWValueChanged: {
            if(lineSeries1.count > 5)
                lineSeries1.remove(0);
            lineSeries1.append(dataFromCpp.wValue.x, dataFromCpp.wValue.y)
            axisX.min = lineSeries1.at(0).x
            axisX.max = lineSeries1.at(lineSeries1.count-1).x
        }
    }

    ChartView {
        id: chartView
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height
        anchors.fill: parent
        animationOptions: ChartView.NoAnimation
        antialiasing: true
        backgroundColor: "#1f1f1f"

        ValueAxis {
            id: axisY1
            min: 0
            max: 100
            gridVisible: false
            color: "#ffffff"
            labelsColor: "#ffffff"
            labelFormat: "%.0f"
        }

        ValueAxis {
            id: axisX
            min: 0
            max: 50
            gridVisible: false
            color: "#ffffff"
            labelsColor: "#ffffff"
            labelFormat: "%.0f"
            tickCount: 5
        }

        LineSeries {
            id: lineSeries1
            name: "signal 1"
            color: "white"
            axisX: axisX
            axisY: axisY1
        }
    }
}
```

The complete example can be found in the following [link](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/questions/47735042).

Comment: How could the above be amended to contain the logic (m_wTimer and wTimeout) in the data.cpp file rather than in the header file itself? I'm comfortable with removing the chart.cpp/h files, but would prefer to leave the logic out of the header file if possible.

Comment: Just move the code to the .cpp, I already did, now do not forget to mark my answer as correct.

Comment: @eyllensc out of interest, could I use the approach you've written above with QXYSeries in c++, to then replace() the entire set of chart data rather than appending each incremental change? I note that QML LineSeries doesn't provide a means for replacing or adding a QVector/QList, this is only possible from c++.

Comment: Ok great, thanks for confirming. In that case I'm going to work on a second version of your code to cater to plotting entire vectors/lists as opposed to individual points, as I can this level of flexibility being quite useful.